# Paypal Payment REST API and CreditCard Payment

Tags: php, rest, api, paypal

Recently I visited Paypal Rest API page https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/. I noticed an IMPORTANT message there please find below screenshot:

[image]

If this API now restrict to process Card Payment then Is Billing Plan and Agreement API (for Recurring/Subscription Payment) also restrict Card payment?

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

The ability to process direct credit card transactions via PayPal REST API for new integrations has been restricted. That means that the "payment_method":"credit_card" option is no longer allowed to be use with any new REST API integrations, including for the Billing Plan and Billing Agreement API's.

We apologize for any inconvenience.

Comment: Ok, Then which method can I use in place of /payments api for process recurring payment?

Comment: We are recommending merchants use Braintree Direct, as shown in the screenshot you provided.